# Creating a user using the SonarQube API returns a 401

Tags: api, sonarqube

I'm trying to create a user using the SaonarQube API (version 6.2 or up).

I have setup a SoapUI project that contains a few test scripts. One of them is login in and creating a user. this one returns a 401 whe the user creation call is done.

The login is used for other calls as well and proves to work. Except for the create user call. The account used to login to SoarQube is member of the System Administror groups.

Below is the raw request.

```
POST http://localhost:9000/api/users/create HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 47
Host: localhost:9000
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
Cookie: JWT-SESSION=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiJBV0ExaGFtX2hnNWdHUWtNNVRHSiIsInN1YiI6ImFkbWluIiwiaWF0IjoxNTEyNzI2NDQwLCJleHAiOjE1MTI5ODU2NDAsImxhc3RSZWZyZXNoVGltZSI6MTUxMjcyNjQ0MDM4MywieHNyZlRva2VuIjoicHRwcXRlYmtzYTR2MTlhaTk3anV0bnVlZW8ifQ.waHqOsMJ9P6FyIOUWuVODl5QcW-IJp10G6oUAvy1DWk; XSRF-TOKEN=ptpqtebksa4v19ai97jutnueeo
Cookie2: $Version=1

login=user01&name=name01&password=%21P%40ssw0rd
```

Below is the raw resoonse

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 08 Dec 2017 09:47:20 GMT
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

BTW: I can create the user using the same values using the UI so there is no issue with he user information, at least it seams so.

Update 1:
Added raw request with querystring parameters

```
POST http://localhost:9000/api/users/create?login=user01&name=name01&password=%21P%40ssw0rd HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 0
Host: localhost:9000
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
Cookie: JWT-SESSION=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiJBV0JHZkVGY0h3bW5UZ0V5QklJNyIsInN1YiI6ImFkbWluIiwiaWF0IjoxNTEzMDExMDM2LCJleHAiOjE1MTMyNzAyMzYsImxhc3RSZWZyZXNoVGltZSI6MTUxMzAxMTAzNjQyNCwieHNyZlRva2VuIjoibmIzdmlpcjAyZmZ1ODJnMzNtdW1hYWdkN3QifQ.ur8eZkW1CwNinx4tInFsbkGLQTHQ6yFjheRfup8Z4fQ; XSRF-TOKEN=nb3viir02ffu82g33mumaagd7t
Cookie2: $Version=1
```

Comment: Are you sending the parameters in the HTTP or in the body of the request ? Because the second choice is no more possible

Comment: Hello, Yes, initially I did send it in the body as noted in the above example. This actually also works for the login call so i thought that might be valid. Just tried to do it as a querystring parameter but this also returns a 401.

Comment: Could you please send the URL you're using ? Thanks

Comment: Oups, in fact as you're receiving a 401, it's most probably because the credentials are badly sent

Comment: Yes, it seams that way but I use the same method for sending credentials in other test cases and that works. I will post the raw request using querystring parameters below.

Comment: I added the post information in the original question

Comment: I don't see how you sent login/password to the HTTP request, where is it ?

Comment: I do the login in a previous request, capture the session cookie an add it to the create user call. Just like i do with any other test case.

`Cookie: JWT-SESSION=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9XXXXXXXXXXXetc`

In the create user call i tried to add the parameters both in the body or in the querystring. Both fail.

`POST http://localhost:9000/api/users/create?login=user01&name=name01&password=%21P%40ssw0rd HTTP/1.1
`

Please check the raw request response snippets above, these are copy pasted from SoapUI output directly.

Comment: @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam i tried the same concept to create a new project using SoapUI. This also required an authenticated call, and it uses a POST reguest with parameters in the body. This one seams to work. The project is created. It looks like the create user call is handled differently. Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Ok, now I understand => what you're trying to do is forbidden as it may be considered as an attack. Cookie should only be used in a web browser. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to use the generated cookie by a web request in a console request (it could be considered as an attack).

You need either to :

- Specify a [user token](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/User+Token) (recommended way)
- Specify a login/password

Comment: Thanks, i got it working now. Still confused what the login endpoint is for and why the **JWT-SESSION** cookie seams to work on for instance the `/api/users/create` endpoint where i really need to specify it.

Comment: For now i will need to user login/password as SoapUI does not seam to handle basis authentication without specifying a password :(

Comment: When using web services, you should never care about cookie/JWT-SESSION. The only way to authenticate is to use basic authentication.

Comment: for those who use postman, try to check whether there are cookies related to your sonarqube host, and , delete them